# $\square+\square+\square=30$, with boxes filled using $1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15$, possibly repeated. How?

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

From the days I started to learn Maths, I've have been taught that

> Adding Odd times Odd numbers the Answer always would be Odd; e.g., 
>   $$3 + 5 + 1 = 9$$

OK, but look at this question

[image: UPSC Question]

This question was solved and the answer was 30, how it was possible? Need a valid explanation please.

Comment: Do you  believe the statement that somebody solved it fairly?  Why?  There is an old riddle that you have three bags and thirty stones.  You need to put the stones in the bags so each bag contains an odd number of stones.  One solution is to put fifteen stones into each of two bags, then put one of those two bags into the third.  That doesn't work here.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, either. Added the `recreational-mathematics` and `puzzle` tags where the question may be better received.

Comment: I didn't downvote.  I am surprised that this got an upvote.  It also got two downvotes (as of this comment).  People seem to agree with my question of why you believe the statement that somebody solved it because of the reason you gave.

Comment: @RossMillikan I liked your analogy a lot!

Comment: It's possible there is a misunderstanding about "XYZ could solve it". It may mean that XYZ correctly answered the question "can you solve this <equation>".. Presumably his solution stated "no, we cannot solve <equation>" for the reason you gave.

Comment: Where you get the question from? A newspaper? A magazine? Or the original exam? I would assume the exam was in English, though there's also the possibility in one of those languages I only know about because of a Unicode block. But even in English there is always the possibility of a misquotation.

Answer (score 6):

You have answered your own question: the sum of an odd number of odd numbers must be odd. Therefore it cannot equal 30.

You should not believe everything you read in a photo on the internet.

Comment: That's so kind of you!

Answer (score 6):

Clearly impossible in base 10. Can it be done in another number base?

In base 5:  $11+11+3=30$

Actually there are many other possibilities!

Another possibility: fill the boxes with $\binom{5}{3}$,15 and 5.

It holds that $\binom{5}{3}+15+5=30$ (base 10). Notice that $\binom{5}{3}=10$. I can't see any rule being violated as I'm using the 2 parenthesis in the list of valid symbols provided in addition to the numbers 5, 3, 15 and 5 and no extra symbol.

Comment: May be! this one makes sense a lot.

Comment: If you do $1+11+13$ you won't even need to use a number twice.

Comment: Or 1+11+15=30 (base 7), just to have another instance without repetition, in another base :).

Answer (score 4):

Do you *have* to fill in *all* three boxes? I would just put 15 in *two* of the boxes, e.g., $$\fbox{ } + \fbox{15} + \fbox{15} = 30,$$ and hope people understand the first box as being an implicit 0.

Answer (score 2):

> you can also repeat the numbers

Wonder if that means $\,11,5+13,5+5=30\,$ (where the $\,,\,$ comma works as 
decimal separator).

Comment: Ooh! so Strange...

Comment: @ArshadAli:  this is the kind of unfair solution I was talking about.  I enjoy puzzles, as in the riddle I wrote in my first comment.  They are not fair at a final exam.

Comment: @RossMillikan Completely agree with your comment. That said, I have no idea what a "*UPSC final exam*" might be. The first page of google hits brings up mainly links to this very puzzle, which is a bit odd in itself.

Comment: Most likely,  UPSC = [Union Public Service Commission](http://www.upsc.gov.in/), notorious for their difficult entrance exams for public employees in India. Check [here](http://www.upsc.gov.in/examinations/previous-question-papers) for some previous exams.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a riddle, I would do : 13,1 + 7,9 + 9

Comment: You didn't like my answer? What about this: (1+3)+19+11 or (1+1)+13+15? These questions are usually asked to check if people think out of the box or not.

Comment: Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery, as the saying goes ;-)

Answer (score 2):

What about 
6+9+15=30?

they don't stay you have to fill the boxes with the numbers in their usual orientation, after all. :-)

Comment: I'm sure this is the solution of the riddle (I had found 6+11+13). Nothing was said about the orientation of the numbers in the boxes...

Answer (score 1):

- Change the base:  $$11_9 + 11_9 + 11_9 = 10+10+10 = 30  \text{.}$$
- Parentheses are in the list of usable box contents.  Commas too.  But you're upper limited to one pair of parens and to seven commas.
  $$(15+15,15)+15 = 30  \\ (15+15,15+15) = 30  \text{.}$$  Here, the parens represent the [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

**Edit:**

Change of base can also be made to work if number repetition were eliminated.
$$  11_{5} + 15_{7} + 13_{9} = 6 + 12 + 12 = 30  \text{.}  $$

Comment: parentheses and commas are in the list for usable symbols, but not the + sign. Your second solution uses an extra plus sign inside the first box, not in the list of allowed symbols :).

Comment: @bluemaster : Meh.  It was late enough I didn't notice.  But, ... [edited]

Answer (score -1):

It's
$$3_3+3_3+3_3=30.$$
Where $3_3$ is read as 3 base 3.